# Minimal degree of polynomial which local-global principle is not effective

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

My question is motivated from celebrated Hasse-Minkowski local-global principle:

A quadratic form over rational number $f $  has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $f$ has solution in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

I am curious about this principle is effective or not in higher degree polynomial, but with only one indeterminate (or homogeneous polynomial with two indeterminate).

By using elementary knowledge about quadratic residue and Hensel's lemma, I found $f(x)=(x^2-2)(x^2-17)(x^2-34)$ has solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{R}$ (and especially in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$), but it has no solution in rational numbers.

My question is this: Is minimal degree of polynomial of one indeterminate which contradicts to local-global principle is 6?

Also, in similar intuition, is there a polynomial irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ which is reducible in every $\mathbb{F}_p$ (or $\mathbb{Q}_p$)?

Comment: The usual answer to your second question is the polynomial $x^4+1$; every local field except $\mathbb{Q}_2$ and every finite field has either $\sqrt{-1}$ or $\sqrt{2}$ or $\sqrt{-2}$, so one of the factorizations $(x^2+\sqrt{-1})(x^2-\sqrt{-1})$, $(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)$ and $(x^2+\sqrt{-2}x-1)(x^2-\sqrt{-2}x-1)$ must exist.

Comment: $x^3-2$ has a root modulo $p$ if $p\equiv2\bmod3$. If $p\equiv1\bmod3$, then $x^2+3$ has a root modulo $p$. So consider $f(x)=(x^3-2)(x^2+3)$.

Comment: $f(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$ is another example to the second question. is not to hard to prove that it's irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. For other part it's riducible mod $p$ for every prime. 
This is simple for $p=2$ or $p=3$. Now if $p>3$ we have that $\left ( \frac{2}{p}\right ) \left ( \frac{3}{p}\right )= \left ( \frac{6}{p} \right )$, then there exist a such that $a^2\equiv 2$ mod $p$, $a^2\equiv 3$ mod $p$ or $a^2\equiv 6$ mod $p$. In the first case we have $f(x)=(x^2+2ax-1)(x^2-2ax-1)$, in the second $f(x)=(x^2+2ax+1)(x^2-2ax+1)$ and in the last $f(x)=(x^2+2c-5)(x^2-2c-5)$